# Python's equivalent to R's grepl and dplyr filter

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I want to find a way to recreate the same command code from R in Python using something similar as the dplyr package. In R I would do this:

```
      library(dplyr)
  df <- data.frame(Countries=c('Brazil','Venezuela','Brazil, Colombia, Paraguay','Argentina','Peru','Andorra,Argentina,Chile,Uruguay'),
               Code=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

df  %>% filter(grepl('(Brazil|Argentina)',Countries))
```

Or even:

```
    a=strsplit(as.character(df$Countries),',')
    a=lapply(a,FUN=function(t) gsub(" ","",t))
    ele=unlist(lapply(a,FUN=function(t) any(t%in%c('Brazil','Argentina'))))
    (df[ele,])
```

The output that I want:

```
                   Countries Code
1                     Brazil    1
2 Brazil, Colombia, Paraguay    3
3                  Argentina    4
4    Argentina,Chile,Uruguay    6
```

In Python I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Countries=['Brazil','Venezuela','Brazil, Colombia, Paraguay','Argentina','Peru','Andorra,Argentina,Chile,Uruguay'], Code=[1,2,3,4,5,6]))

list_=['Brazil','Argentina']
print(df.loc[df['Countries'].isin(list_)])
```

But the output looks like:

```
   Countries  Code
0     Brazil     1
3  Argentina     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for the `.str` extension of `pd.Series` with an object `dtype` (essentially you can call `pd.Series.str....` for a subset of pandas functions specifically for dealing with regular expression and other `string` based operations- however this only works if the array is of dtype "object".

```
mask = df["Countries"].str.contains("Brazil|Argentina")
subset = df.loc[mask]

print(subset)
                         Countries  Code
0                           Brazil     1
2       Brazil, Colombia, Paraguay     3
3                        Argentina     4
5  Andorra,Argentina,Chile,Uruguay     6
```

A neat way you can use this is by using the `.join` function on your `list_` variable to join it into a single string usable by regular expression matching patterns.

```
list_=['Brazil','Argentina']
pattern = "|".join(list_) # Now we have "Brazil|Argentina" as a string

mask = df["Countries"].str.contains(pattern)
subset = df.loc[mask] # Same subset as the previous example
```

See the docs and other methods besides `.str.contains` at the documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html